# JS Code coverage

Tags: javascript, code-coverage

I am a newbie for the testing scenario.
I have one question wanna ask your help.

For example, if I have one web application which implemented from HTML, JS and CSS and calls other APIs.
While this web application is being tested, how to measure "code coverage" in an HTML/JS/CSS browser application IN THE BROWSER when doing functional testing? Any Javascript plugins to see how much of the client code was running during the tests?

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: Have you checked Chrome's DevTool code coverage? https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes

Comment: I've already tried it.  But it is not exactly tool I am looking for.  Anyway, thanks for suggestion.   @Danosaure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by:

> "code coverage"

as your question is a little hard to understand.

But I'm assuming you are referring to some form of visualizer like [this one](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) that allows you to see step by step how your code is being executed and why it behaves as it does in a given program. As to a browser plugin or tool existing for the purpose you outline I am not aware of one that can achieve what it is I think you want. That being said, the way you phrased your question is a little strange and some clarification would go a long way to help me or someone else better answer your question.

On the other more likely hand, you refer to the actual concept of [code coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage), a percentage that refers to more or less the amount of code run when tests are being run (Franci Penov does a much better job explaining [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195008/what-is-code-coverage-and-how-do-you-measure-it)). Google Chrome does CSS and JS code coverage in-browser (at least according to [these release notes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes)).

[This is a link for a Javascript code coverage testing tool](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/)

I hope my very shaky understanding of this issue helps!

Comment: @PorrPor No problem, it would do me a huge favor if you accepted it as the answer