# How can I measure test coverage in QT?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtest

I use Qt Creator 4.8.2.

I already have a working program 'A' and added a subproject 'B' for testing.

I am trying to do a unit test using qtest.

How can I measure test coverage for Project 'A'?

If you have examples, please comment it.

Comment: Did you consider using tools that measure it?

Comment: I didn't understand what "tool" you were talking about. What is the name of the tool?

Comment: "Tool" in this context is an application that can measure the code coverage when you run your test.

Comment: In fact, I didn't know if there was such a tool. Can you recommend a free tool that can be used in Qt?

Comment: @ryu Please read the [suggested dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195008/what-is-code-coverage-and-how-do-you-measure-it).  It contains plenty of information regarding tools etc.