# How to get code coverage report without XCTest/XCUITest(only for manual run)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automated-tests, code-coverage

Code coverage report generate for unit test and UI Test only. In my case I need without written unit and UI test to generate code coverage for manual run the app.

Comment: Coverage refers to [how much of your source code is tested](https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/software-testing/code-coverage), and you need to [execute tests to measure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195008/what-is-code-coverage-and-how-do-you-measure-it). You need to elaborate what you mean by **coverage for manual run** without unit test or UI test.

Comment: For android doing the same they generate the report for manual run app. Trying to the same in the iOS part.

Comment: What do you want to be the contents of this report?

Comment: How much code covered in source code of the swift file. It shown as a percentage. File format is .xcresult

Comment: But if you do not execute a `test` how do you get `coverage`? Code coverage refers to the amount of code that is `tested`.

Answer (score 1):

class SampleUITests: XCTestCase {

```
override func setUpWithError() throws {

    continueAfterFailure = false 
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
}

func testExample() throws {
    sleep(60)
    XCTAssertTrue(true)
}
```

We can run XCUItest and whatever we want to do with your app between the sleep time end. After that Xcode generate the .xcresult in the derived data path. There you can find your code coverage report.